# How can I resolve the “Resource ID #8” error message in MYSQL/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

```
function show_post($user_id)
             {
                 global $database;
                 $post = array();

                 $sql = sprintf("SELECT body,stamp FROM post WHERE user_id = '%s' ORDER BY stamp DESC ",$user_id);

                 $result = $database->query($sql);

                 while( $data = $database -> fetch_array($result))
                 {
                        $post[] = array(
                         'user_id' => $user_id,
                         'body' => $data->'body',
                         'stamp' => $data->'stamp'
                         );


                 }

                   return $post;

             }
```

---

```
$posts = $link->show_post($_SESSION['user_id']);

         if(count($posts))
         {
        ?>
        <table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' width='500'>
        <?php
             foreach($posts as $key => $list)
             {
                echo "<tr valign='top'>\n";
                echo "<td>".$list['user_id'] ."</td>\n";
                echo "<td>".$list['body'] ."<br/>\n";
                echo "<small>".$list['stamp'] ."</small></td>\n";
                echo "</tr>\n";

             }


         ?>
            </table>
         <?php
         }else
         {
             echo "nothing entered";

         }
```

This returns: Resource id #8

Can you assist me in finding the problem?

Comment: That's not an error message. You printed out the connection handle `$database` somewhere. And that doesn't much look like the code where this is happening.

Comment: Error is not present in the provided code block ... it's in somewhere else where probably you are trying to echo a dataset/DB handle like

Comment: If you're doing fetch_array then $data->'body' isn't the right way to access that; it should be $data['body']. Also, your sprintf doesn't appear to be escaped and is open to SQL Injection (even if user_id comes from the session now, it's still a _very_ good practice to always escape every parameter regardless).

Answer (score 0):

Add this and see what it echo's back

```
function show_post($user_id)
             {
                 global $database;
                 $post = array();

                 $sql = sprintf("SELECT body,stamp FROM post WHERE user_id = '%s' ORDER BY stamp DESC ",$user_id);

                 $result = $database->query($sql);

                 while( $data = $database -> fetch_array($result))
                 {
                        echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre><br />';

                        $post[] = array(
                         'user_id' => $user_id,
                         'body' => $data->'body',
                         'stamp' => $data->'stamp'
                         );


                 }

                   return $post;

             }
```

Unless that print_r($data) prints something odd, I don't see what is wrong with that block of code. May have something to do with the database class you are using.

Comment: print_r($data) returns  1 1 1 1 1 (for the user_id) which is the session id (Assigned 1 ) and Resource id #8

Comment: i think the issue is with  $post[] = array(
                        ***
                         'body' => $data->'body',
                         'stamp' => $data->'stamp'
                         );

Comment: You may want to try it once with fetch_assoc() instead of fetch_array().

Comment: Mêmes résultats ! I mean same results with fetch_assoc()

Comment: @Zimzat i changed it to $data['body'] and commented out mysql_error from my fetch array function and its working now ...** '//or die ($result_set."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); '** though its working i feel some thing is still not right  :) thanks anyway